# Cannot set up RVM in Xubuntu on VMware

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I am attempting to install RVM on Xubuntu and am having no luck getting the OS/terminal to recognize rvm as something that it can call.

I have been following the instructions here: http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

I first call:

```
sudo bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
```

This seems to be executing correctly. I then run:

```
sudo echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bashrc
```

The text is appended to the end of the file.

Next I close out the terminal completely and reopen it. I try running:

```
type rvm | head -1
```

It responds:

```
bash: type: rvm: not found
```

If I try just calling rvm it responds:

```
The program 'rvm' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong, I cannot seem to determine what that is. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the sudo version of the install script, you have installed the multi user version of rvm, and then you ran the single user "sourcing" script with sudo...

When using the multi user version, rvm will not install into `$HOME/.rvm`, but in `/usr/local/rvm`.

Therefore you will have to use the multi user way to source the rvm script, and that is to add your user to the `rvm` group.

As shine already posted though, you probably didn't want to install system wide rvm to start with.

Comment: Oh I see, the reason I was using sudo though was because when I did not it says rning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/archives/wayneeseguin-rvm-stable.tgz: Permission 
Warning: denied

Comment: That sounds like an odd thing for it to say. It should just work magically and install itself into your `~/.rvm` if you don't use sudo. Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: No, it's still doing it actually.

Comment: Got it, created a new virtual drive and reinstalled. I must have messed up a setting somewhere, works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you tried to first install `apt-get ruby-rvm` this is broken and unsupported version of rvm, we have lots of problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it with `sudo`. You have installed it for a root and you're not a root.

RVM should be installed in your home folder, you don't need superuser privileges for that.

Comment: RVM can be installed system wide by using sudo. The reason he's getting the error is because he's using the wrong way of sourcing rvm.